# How in Chromium Embedded detect if we are running as subprocess?

Tags: c++, chromium-embedded

When using single executable for Chromium Embedded Framework 3 subprocess, how can program detect if it is running as main executable or as a subprocess?

I found that main process runs with command line switch `--type=zygote`, but subprocesses are not.

Will it always be correct that (in pseudo language):

```
if (command line switch --type=zygote not found) {
    we are in subprocess
}
```

?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, I believe so, we successfully used that technique.

```
          if ( wcsstr(lpCmdLine, L"type") == NULL ){
             //  we have no subprocess type so we are the main process
          }
```